# Is there a way to select a line in a database with null in a field only if there is no line with values?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a db2 table that store brand names. In each line, we have a supplier ID and a country. So I can use that to filter out the brands.
Now the lines also contain a customer ID and a Group.
Either the customer is filled (and the group NULL), the group is filled (and the customer NULL), or they're both NULL.

What I'm trying to do is this : get all the lines that match this specific supplier and country, but with a special filter on the customer and group.
If I have only lines with NULL in both fields, returns all these lines.
If some lines have the group specified, then return only the lines with that group (and ignore those with a NULL group)
BUT if some lines have the customer specified, then return only the lines with the customer specified and ignore the others (the lines with the group or the lines with NULL NULL)

Is that doable in SQL, specifically DB2, or do I need to get ALL the lines and filter later during processing ? (in that case, PHP)

Since you guys want me to show some code, here's what I came up with, after some research (never used "WITH" before)
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=e7a54ff6eec8ed4be2594644ba3224bd

EDIT : Finally got it working by myself, dunno if it's the best way to do it though
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=ce7c99d8a37e3dad90900440127730e4

EDIT 2 : I merged the 3 subqueries into 1 by using CASE, I think it's better, but I'm not sure.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=b581532553b5619d9cdc388d54619836

Comment: Try something then.

Comment: Search for case statements in SQL and share your efforts.

Comment: If you dont try you wont progress. The most liked is you are using `Something = null` instead `Somthing IS NULL`

Comment: It's certainly possible to do what you ask in plain SQL. However, your explanation has a few holes in it. Please provide some sample data and expected results. A few rows will go a long way for us to understand exactly what you need.

Comment: Added a dbfiddle since apparently you want me do show you data and expected results.